# Add data to an array on a button click in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have an array

```
let newLinkedArray=[];
            newDocArray && newDocArray.map(doc => {
            newLinkedArray.push({DocName:doc, Type:"Checks", DocID:0})
             })
```

which doesn't change and after a click on a button that contains data I want to add that data to this array which contains the same field. On every click on a button, I want to push each data to this array. As per my code the data which is selected only added to that array.

```
let newAddArr=[{
                "DocName":selectedRow !== null? docTolinked[selectedRow].ShortPath:'',
                "Type" :selectedRow !== null? docTolinked[selectedRow].Type:'',
                "DocID": selectedRow !== null? docTolinked[selectedRow].DocID:''
            }]
            let newAddLinkArr =[]
            newAddLinkArr =addDoc1 && [...newLinkedArray, ...newAddArr];
```

This is my code. When I click on a button 'addDoc1' flag is set.How to add on every button click selected row to this array?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you prefer functional or stateful components. This is a solution that uses functional approach:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
const Elem = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
  const addNewRow = useCallback(() => {
    // selectedRow comes from somewhere else
    const newAddArr = {
      "DocName":selectedRow !== null? docTolinked[selectedRow].ShortPath:'',
      "Type" :selectedRow !== null? docTolinked[selectedRow].Type:'',
      "DocID": selectedRow !== null? docTolinked[selectedRow].DocID:''
    };
    setArray([...array, newAddArr]);
  }, [array, setArray]);
  return (
    <button onClick={addNewRow}>Click me!</button>
  );
};
```